# I don't understand two points in the following sentence

Tags: meaning

I don't understand two points in the following sentence:

> I have quite a lot of family and when I was growing up it was in a
>   real, good, ordinary family – you couldn’t really get away with
>   anything.

1) A lot of family means a big family?
2) What does "get away with anything" means?

Source: http://www.mirror.co.uk/3am/celebrity-news/paul-mccartneys-tips-staying-fit-5788063

Comment: 1) yes and 2) [any dictionary could have told you](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-away-with)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Quite a lot of family
```

is rather a colloquial expression, without hearing the tone of voice it's hard to be sure what was intended. I would read it as implying an extended multi-generation family, but I think there is more implied than just size. A more conventional:

```
 I come from a large family
```

would be sufficient if only size were under consideration. I would interpret "a lot of family" as implying that the members were in close, perhaps daily, contact. The treatment of "family" as thing experienced and measured as "a lot" has a slightly oppressive over-tone. It's likely that all adults would expect to discipline all the children, hence the children could not easily misbehave; they could not

```
 get away with anything
```